# How to strip the path prefix in Kubernetes Traefik ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, k3s

I'm using k3s v1.22.7 on Ubuntu 20.04. I want `/bar/xyz` to be `/xyz` to the pods. Without the middleware I'm properly routed to the pods, with it I get `404` from Traefik as though the stripping from `replacePathRegex`/`stripPrefix` happens before the Ingress path evaluation. Examples online all have it like that though...

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: strip-prefix
spec:
  #replacePathRegex:
  #  regex: ^/(?:[^/]+)/(.*)
  #  replacement: /$1
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /bar
      - /baz
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: strip-prefix@kubernetescrd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.org
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /bar
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: foo-service
            port:
              number: 5001
      - path: /baz
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: foo-service
            port:
              number: 5002
```

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the middleware needs the namespace prefixed, so either

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: strip-prefix
  # No namespace defined
spec:
  stripPrefixRegex:
    regex:
    - ^/[^/]+
---
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-strip-prefix@kubernetescrd
```

or

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: strip-prefix
  namespace: example # Namespace defined
spec:
  stripPrefixRegex:
    regex:
    - ^/[^/]+
---
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: example-strip-prefix@kubernetescrd
```

should work.

([Source](https://community.traefik.io/t/how-to-configure-middleware-with-kubernetes-ingress-middleware-xyz-does-not-exist/5016))